# Delete items from a llist box in c# through if and else

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitems

I'm doing an exercise where I need to delete items from a listbox...
I already know how to do it one by one and all at the same time.

I was wondering how to do it like: if an item were selected, delete only that item, else delete all.

I'm trying for a little while and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you show us your code? We'd like to see what you have tried so far and help you from there.

Comment: Where is the code you've already tried?

Comment: ListBox.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox.SelectedIndex)

Comment: We are going to need to see some code to help you.  Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you want to post a solution to the problem then post an answer, don't edit an answer into the question.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    listBox.Items.RemoveAt(listBox.SelectedIndex);

    listBox.Items.Clear();
 }
```

I was thinking on use these two lines in an "If and Else" but I realize that works with "Try and Catch", like:

```
try
{
    listBox.Items.RemoveAt(listBox.SelectedIndex);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    listBox.Items.Clear();
}
```